# Using DocuSign API, how does one revoke access to a specific Connected App?

Tags: docusignapi

I need to programmatically revoke access to a Connected App similar to how it can be manually done via:
Manage Profile -> Connected Apps -> Revoke (a specific App)

What's the DocuSign API end point that can be used for this?

Comment: Is this app access (consent) organization-wide? meaning it was given to all users in the org and you want to revoke to all users in the org? you can do that, but if it's a single user - you cannot

Answer (score 0):

If the app was added for an organization and all its users ([administrative consent](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-admin-consent-internal/)) then you can revoke this consent, again for the entire organization and all its users using the API.
If this is a single user that provided consent, you can only revoke it manually.